# Moment JS Array Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, momentjs

I simply want the time from the second column, then to add 2 hours. I am using the momentJS library. This is what I have so far.

```js
function myFunction(){

    var cellData = [];
    var i;

    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");

    for (i=0; i<myTable.rows.length; i++) {

        cellData.push(myTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);

    }
    var x = [moment(cellData).add(2, 'h').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm')];
    alert(x);
  
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A<td>
            <td>2016-08-24 15:45</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A<td>
            <td>2016-08-24 16:45</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Do you want time in string or in date format ignoring the datestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not close `<td>` tag properly that's why `myTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML` not return date string.

Try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function myFunction() {

  var cellData = [];
  var i;
  var x = [];
  var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");

  for (i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length; i++) {
    cellData.push(myTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
    date = moment(cellData[i], "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").add(2, 'h').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm');
    x.push(date);
  }


  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1">

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>2016-08-24 15:45</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>2016-08-24 16:45</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Can you justify why you need jQuery for such task? jQuery doesn't do magic.

Comment: @AdamAzad yes you are right i forgot to remove that

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing an error because you are trying to access all the rows which includes table header's  rows also

you might considering traversing only tbody's rows
check the following code snippet

```js
window.onload=function(){
  myFunction();
}
function myFunction(){

var cellData = [];
var i;

var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
var cellData=[];
  $("#myTable tbody tr").each(function(){
  var date=$(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
    
  var dateModified=moment(date).add(2, 'h').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A')
  
  cellData.push(dateModified);
});
  console.log(cellData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" border="1">

<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>A<td>
        <td>2016-08-24 15:45</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>A<td>
        <td>2016-08-24 16:45</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Hope this helps
check this link http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/LRJGaJ
Another thing, you cannot add whole array at a time. you might consider adding each item at a time and then insert into an array

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
function myFunction(){

    var x = [];  
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");

    for (var i=0; i<myTable.rows.length; i++) {  
         x.push(moment(myTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML).add(2, 'h').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm')); 
    }
    alert(x);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of problems.

#### HTML

You haven't closed the first `<td>` tags of rows.

```
    <td>A</td>
    <!--  ^ -->
    <td>2016-08-24 15:45</td>
    <td>C</td>
```

#### JavaScript

`cellData` is an array, and you cannot pass arrays of date strings to momentJS. Instead, create the momentJS instance and push it its formatted string to `cellData`

```js
function myFunction(){

var cellData = [];
var i;

var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");

for (i=0; i<myTable.rows.length; i++) {

    var momentObj = moment(myTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML).add(2, 'h').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm');
    cellData.push(momentObj);
  

}

  console.log(cellData); // ["08/24/2016 05:45", "08/24/2016 06:45"]

}

myFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>2016-08-24 15:45</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>2016-08-24 16:45</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you alot for your response. I didn' know you couldn't arrays of date strings to momentJS. This works for me.

Comment: You're most welcomed, you can accept the answer if it helped you :).